Im getting 403 Error When put image to api
I'm getting 403 response with this error page. I'm sure my API token is correct, because my other functions working very well.
<Error>
     <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
         <Message>Access denied.</Message>
             <Details>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Details>
<StringToSign>GET 1722666597 /</StringToSign>
</Error>

I checked my headers against the API documentation. It seems good. My other headers for other request, they work good. except this.
This is API Doc

curl --request PUT 
--url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/backend-fishes-storage-prod/hpleg1o4wez3e7mvy1sivhep9dw6?GoogleAccessId=services-storage-client%40ecstatic-baton-230905.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1656619087&Signature=aMeN%2FVW4I6LDgLRUEW0jzJqeA89gRpjn0TBcGMEnal3RU1iGqe0uOraHainV5qUw6tRPEBRBJ6rMeu9x0AmX6OC3Q8cCCmBUMs4k1jCQOnnCNgkttpU7ov%2FeZ9WpPr47rTQSd5np7jCG3EWVEBhNeP25%2BTx5JlKQQ8UErP%2Bc46Lr%2Bj28wgLw%2BeeVjO4sVjEnLx3djoZD0Htei5XR0YQKVr%2FGDbS4iBOmjPsD5g4txKM6071zft%2BFK6U7I%2FfWjef2w4Nx%2BVvdATkNRpVEzbkAv1lBWMhfrOLy5koJfGepFk0BGQbTXNokhFCQYxzQuJBeC1xubKHzZSQLCVnTXt4EXA%3D%3D' 
--header 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="fishpic.jpg"; filename*=UTF-8''''''fishpic.jpg' 
--header 'Content-Md5: EA5w4bPQDfzBgEbes8ZmuQ==' 
--header 'Content-Type:' 
--data-binary @fishpic.jpg

This my header
 case .putPhoto(let model, _):
               return [
                   "Content-Disposition" : model.directUpload.headers.contentDisposition,
                   "Content-Md5" : model.directUpload.headers.contentMD5,
                   "Content-Type" : ""
               ]

And my httpBody
switch self {
           case .putPhoto(_, let image):
               request.httpBody = image
}

Can someone help me?

Okey, i found the problem. url is changing when i send request.
func request() -> URLRequest {
        var url: URL
        switch self {
            
                case .putPhoto(model: let model, _):
                    url = URL(string: model.directUpload.url)!
                default:
                    guard var components = URLComponents(string: baseUrl) else {
                        fatalError("URL Error")
                    }
                    components.path = path
                    url = components.url!
                }

Now, i am checking if httpMethod equal .putPhoto then send url directly. Thats solved my problem.
